# Como passar nome de arquivo com acentuação e espaços como parâmetro para arquivo shell script

Tags: linux, shell, parâmetros

Eu densenvolvi um shell script que recebe a localização de um arquivo e faz diversas manipulações nele, ex:
./processa.sh path/arquivo.txt

Porém quando envio um nome de arquivo como parâmetro que contenha espaços ele dá erro, pois coloca '\ ' em cada espaço, e assim é interpretado pelo bash como um diretório.
Ex: path/nome do arquivo.txt
Saída: path/nome\ do\ arquivo.txt

Como evitar isso?

Comment: Que sistema operacional é?

Comment: @Tony Linux - Ubuntu

Comment: Como está fazendo a leitura dos parâmetros? Não está usando as variáveis: $N (N > 0) para pegar os parâmetros?

Comment: a leitura está correta, eu pego com $1 e coloco em uma variável. Quando vai sem espaço ele funciona direitinho.

Comment: no comeco do script `IFS=$'\n` e no fim `unset IFS`

Comment: Funciona se você colocar aspas duplas em volta da variável? `"$@"` ou `"$1"`?

Comment: Aspas dupla também na chamada: `./processa.sh "path/nome do arquivo.txt"`, senão cada palavra separada por espaço vai ser considerada um parâmetro diferente: $1, $2 e etc...

Comment: O que @Wakim flw faz sentido, dessa forma eu trato o parâmetro como uma string só, vou testar tbm se existe alguma diferença entre usar " ou '

Comment: Na verdade na chamada você pode usar `\ ` ou aspas duplas (de qualquer forma o sistema lê tudo como uma variável só), no uso da variável você deve usar aspas duplas para escapar os espaços. Veja: http://www.unix.com/os-x-apple-/208819-file-paths-spaces-variable.html para exemplos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A saída foi usar aspas duplas como o Wakim e o Antonio mencionaram, sendo assim estou marcando a questão como resolvida.